# react vs angularjs code conncept

Tags: reactjs

I am new in React and I have an experience in Angularjs.
In Angularjs  I have two components and one service.
The service includes HTTP calls to the server, the calls are common for these two components. so I didn't duplicate my code because I have this service dependency to the components.

I see that there is no service methodology in React,
How do I do that?

Comment: The same way? That has nothing to do with react or angular, it's just architecture.

Answer (score 0):

While angular is a powerful framework and can handle everything for you. React is powerful as a library to handle view only. You should not let it handle the data flow.

Instead, you can use redux to handle the data flow. You can put the HTTP calls in the `actions` and handle data change in `reducer`. Redux will handle the data flow and finally pass data to React as props for you :)